# Jasmine Angular Tests Sometimes Pass and Sometimes Do Not, Depending on Describe Prefix

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

**Background**: I'm working on an Angular project, using Jasmine + Karma to run unit tests.

**Problem**:
I have a test, A.

When I use `fdescribe` on A's test suite, A *passes*, and all other tests are skipped.

However, when I run A's test suite using just `describe`, it *fails*.

---

Furthermore, I have a test, B, that fails.

This has happened twice now:

I change `fdescribe` to `describe` on A- no other tests have `fdescribe`.
I put `xdescribe` on B's test suite.

- I run the tests once: the tests *completely terminate* upon reaching
  test B, which fails.
- I run the tests a second time: *same behavior*.
- I run the tests a third time: my tests *run all the way through*, and

  - A fails (as described above)
  - B is reported as skipped (but the same error message is printed out)

---

Am I missing some nuance of `fdescribe` and `xdescribe`? My tests within `xdescribe` are still (sometimes) failing, and causing later tests to not run. Meanwhile, tests that pass with `fdescribe` fail when the `f` is removed.

If it's relevant, both tests are failing with an error:

`"Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL thrown".`

The ultimate goal is, of course, to fix this error, but that's proving hard to do when it keeps disappearing depending on the suite prefix (to be sure, figuring out what's going on with the prefixes is the focus of this question).

I'm happy to include more information, but I'm unsure what information will be helpful to include in the first place. Furthermore, I'm in a situation where I really can't share details about the code itself, and if non-trivial details about that are required, I unfortunately may not be able to provide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this exact same problem. What I found is that there is likely one of several things happening.

1. Something asynchrounous is not being handled properly and therefore data is sometimes set properly and at other times is not.
2. If you are working with the local storage, the same problems can exist with asynchronous data.
3. Tests are not properly isolated and something is changed in one test that then effects later tests. Running the test separately eliminates this.